# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in Laravel on Excel sheet download

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to make an Excel sheet in Laravel by joining three tables to make the result of the query to be output in an Excel sheet.

Model to retrieve query result:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {
    protected $table= 'product_master';
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';

    public static function download() { 
        $data=DB::table('product_master')
            ->join('subcategory_master', 'product_master.subcategory_id', '=', 'subcategory_master.id')
            ->join('category_master', 'product_master.category_id', '=', 'category_master.id')
            ->select('product_master.product_id','product_master.product_name','product_master.part_number','category_master.category_name','subcategory_master.subcategory_name','product_master.net_quandity','gross_weight','product_master.product_type','product_master.description')
            ->where('delete_status','=','0')->get();
        return($data);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Product;
use Excel;

class ExcelController extends Controller {
    public function downloadExcel(Request $request, $type) {
        $data = Product::download()->all();

        return Excel::create('productmaster', function($excel) use ($data) {
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data) {
                $sheet->fromarray($data);
            });
        })->download($type);
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('downloadExcel/{type}', 'ExcelController@downloadExcel');
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error occurring?

Comment: $sheet->fromArray($data); in the controller

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your query result is an array that contains Product Objects. Objects are key -> value. But the excel tool expects there to be only values.

Your query result:

```
[['id'=>12, 'name'=>'Fidget Spinner'], ['id'=>13, 'name'=>'Shampoo'], ...]
```

What it should be:

```
[[12,'Fidget Spinner'], [13, 'Shampoo'], ...]
```

Try doing this:

```
$data= Product::download()->all();
foreach($data as $k => $v){
   $data[$k] = array_values($v->getAttributes());
}
```

Comment: when i try this code it produce the following:  FatalErrorException
Call to undefined method stdClass::getAttributes()

Comment: thanks a lot kai    ----- i changed the code to   :::::   `public function downloadExcel(Request $request, $type)
 {
  
  $data= Product::download()->all();
  foreach($data as $k => $v){
   $v=(array) $v;
   $data[$k] = (array_values($v));
  } `
    this works   really thankful to u for ur push to the sucess